# Is there a way to load a psql DB dump file to a remote SQL Server (w/out executing any code in SQL Server itself)?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

Is there a way to load a PostgreSQL DB dump file to a remote SQL Server database? Eg. is there a way [`BCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#download-the-latest-version-of-bcp-utility) could do this or anything in the [`mssql-tools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15) package?

I have a database in a PostgreSQL DBMS that I am periodically creating a dump file for like...

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --format=custom -d mydb > mydb.dump
```

...and can move it into a NFS or FTP mount which is also mounted on a centralized data movement server (basically I run an [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) instance here for managing scheduling). From here I can connect to another server hosting a SQL Server instance. I would like to import this dump file into a DB on the SQL Server remotely (ie. running code and scheduling from the data movement server) (normally I write large tables to this SQL Server instance via the `bcp` utility from `mssql-tools`, but not sure how to handle this dump file). **I have access credentials to the MSSQL DB, but can't install any new applications, code, etc on the server**.

Rarely deal w/ DB stuff. Anyone know if this is possible (or if there is a better / more conventional way to do this kind of thing)?

Comment: BTW for anyone else trying to do this, that pg_dump statement is just for example. Really, the way I'm doing it is based on the SO answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6567036/8236733) that helps generalize the dump output.

Comment: You could use SSIS, I think that can export directly from Postgres to SQL Server

Comment: @Charlieface At a quick look, seems like I need to run SSIS on the same server as the MSSQL DBMS ( https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/ ). I need to be able to do such a migration from a remote linux server (I have access to the MSSQL server, but can't install any new applications, code, etc on it). Do LMK if I am misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I can't imagine why you think that is the case, it's just normal connection settings, you can do it from your own PC as long as you have an open SQL connection to the server