# Is there any possible way to convert PostgreSQL database to MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, migration

I am using Postgres db. I need to migrate this database to Microsoft SQL Server database. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this command:**

```
pg_dump -U username your_db_name > db_backup.sql --column-inserts
```

**The --column-inserts option generates INSERT statements possible for each row of data and should be compatible, but you may have to change the syntax just a little bit. (And it may cause data-loss, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)**

**Then just simply open the `.sql` file and run it inside SqlServer**

Comment: There's also some tools out there: https://www.dbsofts.com/articles/postgresql_to_sql_server/

And I'd also suggest to check this answer from a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6567036/6104961

Comment: I tried that tool. But not working for me.