# SQL Server Import Export Wizard Error

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to import some tables via a very old ODBC Driver (FairCom c-tree) and I can't get the wizard in SQL 2012 Express to work. I've been using the OdbcConnection.GetSchema Method to match up against the ProviderDescriptors.xml file however there seems to be no ORDINAL_POSITION value in the schema. Is there anyway to get past this? I can preview the data fine but get an error about the ORDINAL_POSITION and am told to go and fix up the ProviderDescriptors.xml file.

Thanks.

[image: Error]

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add the precise error text, otherwise it isn't clear exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Hi. I've just updated the original post to include a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to create a DSN for your data source, you might have success selecting the data out of it directly using [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

See this thread:
[Migrating from PostgreSQL to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711028/migrating-from-postgres-to-sql-server-2008)

When editing the ProviderDescriptors.xml file, be sure to change the one located in the Program Files (x86) tree if you installed the 64-bit version of SQL Server.