# SSIS OleDB Datasource with POSTGres

Tags: postgresql, ssis, oledb

I am working on SSIS and get trouble with POSTGres.
Because I need to build a command text from variables, so that I have to use the Ole DB Datasource to retrieve data from a Postgres server.
I have search alot pages in internet but not found any good provider (it is not reasonable with fee granted tool such as Devard :(, Postgres is free, it's drivers and provider should be free also).
Does someone can give me a hand on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use an OLEDB provider? Have you tried using an ODBC data source with the (free) [PostgreSQL ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/)?

Comment: You may be interested in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40667376/2144390).

Comment: Hi Gord, yes, I need Ole DB for building dynamic queries. ODBC data source not support to build query from variables.