# Migrating Appian's internal DB from PostgreSQL to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, appian

For all non-Appian SQL specialists: Appian is a low-code platform which needs two central datastores. The database `appian_internal` contains details about Appian's internal objects such as general interface definitions, rules etc. and their configurations. This database is initially created by the platform and usually nobody expect the platform itself touches this database. No business data is stored there.

I read that Appian stores data there in an encrypted manner. All these points support my hypothesis that a simple [migration from PostgreSQL to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723188/migration-of-database-from-postgres-to-ms-sql-servr) will not work.

**The question**

Currently, we have our `appian_internal` database running as a (cloud-based) PostgreSQL, but we are aiming for a (Azure) SQL managed instance - what is the way forward?

Does somebody have experience with that issue? Is it possible to take the `appian_internal` database of a different environment assuming that it is only updated during a platform upgrade?

PS: I hope this is the right forum for a question which is somewhere between infrastructure and SQL and the proprietary low-code platform Appian - I posted it here for the sake of a wider audience. The [search of Appian's community](https://community.appian.com/search?q=appian_internal%20migration&search=community) was not successful since this is a rather technical question for folks who runs the Appian platform on premise.

Comment: Even if you could migrate it, what if it uses postgre drivers so it won't be able to talk to sql server anyway. how do you specify the connection to the database in Appian?

Comment: [Appian already works with SQL Server](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/23.3/System_Requirements.html#databases) so what are you actually asking? How to *move the data* from one database to the other? The safest option would be to use an [Azure PostgreSQL database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/postgresql). All databases have custom features and offer only basic compliance with the ANSI SQL standard.