# Good way to copy data from SQL Server to Posgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I am using OPENQUERY through an ODBC connection to insert records from SQL server to Postgres. 
But it's very slow - a few minutes for 10000 records.
Also, SQL Server Service crashes when amount of data gets too large.

Anybody knows a better way ?

Comment: Have you looked at this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres

Comment: Have a look here:http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding

Answer (score 2):

Export the data in CSV format using a db utility command.

Import the data using the postgres `COPY` command.

Comment: thanks.is there a way to output CSV from SQL server with column headers and encoded special chars ?

Comment: Try reading [the Export documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The standard and the simplest way is to use SSIS built-in Import/Export feature. You can find the steps in another SO [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919468/1780760).