# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]

Tags: sql, postgresql, odbc, ssms

I have followed the steps listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919468/3184087) answer from another thread but when I try to click `Next >` on the destination screen I get the error:

```
TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

The operation could not be completed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have:

1. Installed `PostgreSQL ODBC Driver` on the source server
2. Added in `ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit)` a `PostgreSQL Unicode` driver `User DSN` (also tried a `System DSN`) source named `postgres` (settings are all correct as the Test runs fine)
3. Inside SSMS right-clicked on the database I want to export from and selected *Tasks -> Export Data*
4. Chose *SQL Server Native Client* on the source screen and entered the credentials for SQL Authentication
5. Chose *.NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC* as the destination driver
6. Entered the below connection string
7. Hit `Next >` and the error pops up

My connection string is: `Dsn=postgres;Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};server=<servername>;port=<port>;database=postgres;uid=<user>;pwd=<pass>` (the things between `<>` are actually filled out, just redacted for post).

Just in case it matters, I am trying to export from my SQL database into my PostgreSQL database.

Here are versions for everything:

- SQL Server Management Studio: v17.5 (`About` window shows this *and* below value)
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: 14.0.17224.0
- Source Database: SQL Server 11.0.2100.60
- Source Server: Windows Server 2012 R2
- Source ODBC: 32-bit
- Destination Database: pgAdmin 3.0
- Destination Server: Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: (1) The "error in [your] title" doesn't appear to be complete. Please put the full error into the body of your question. (2) I suggest using a System DSN rather than a User DSN, and given that you *have* such a DSN, reducing your connection string to `Dsn=postgres;uid=<user>;pwd=<pass>` as all the other attributes should be in that DSN...

Comment: @TallTed I have added in the complete error. I tried a System DSN on the source server and reducing the connection string (`Dsn=postgres;uid=<user>;pwd=<pass>`) but the same error is occuring. If it matters, with that shortened string the `Source -> Driver` box is empty/missing.

Comment: (1) The DSN specified by `NamedConnectionString`→`Dsn` includes the `Driver` setting, so there's no need for `Source`→`Driver`. (2) Are all components current? You've provided no version details -- and they are often relevant. (3) I'm wondering if there's a bitness issue. See articles [1](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) and [2](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin).

Comment: @TallTed I've added all version information I can think of to OP. Please let me know if there's anything else that I've left out that's important.

Comment: (1) Are *all* components, including Windows, 32-bit? Or only the "source ODBC" (by which I think you mean the ODBC driver)? (2) I'm fairly sure your "destination database" is not pgAdmin 3.0, but some version of the PostgreSQL DBMS; please give that version. (3) Is SSMS on the same or a different machine than SQL Server 2012? (4) Note that your SQL Server 2012 is [the original, unpatched, release version](http://sqlserverversions.blogspot.com/#sql2012), and you will likely benefit from applying [Service Pack 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56040).

Comment: @TallTed The OS' are 64-bit. The DSN are 32-bit. When I open my pgAdmin console it says "pgAdmin 4 Version 3.0". SSMS is on a server with Server 2012 (hosting source DB). The destination is on a different server, also running Server 2012. Upgrading the servers aren't in my pay grade, unfortunately.

Comment: (1) Just as SSMS is not SQL Server, pgAdmin is not PostgreSQL. Try executing `SELECT version();` through pgAdmin, or through your ODBC DSN (and maybe put output into your question). (2) Is SQL Server 2012 64-bit or 32-bit? Check output of `SELECT @@version;` (maybe put it into your question) and again, see [this article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin). (3) I'm pretty sure you just need to install the 64-bit ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL, and configure a System DSN for it. (For cleanest environment, I suggest dropping the PostgreSQL User DSN(s) you've created.)