# Exporting from SQL Server to Postgres ERROR: column is of type boolean but expression is of type integer

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I am using SSMS to export a table into my Postgres DB as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919468/691928).  Everything is going great, the table and columns are created in Postgres, but when the data is to be loaded it errors out with the following error message:

```
Error 0xc020844b: Data Flow Task 1: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42804] ERROR: column "XYZ" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer;
```

I understand the issue, but not sure how to resolve it as I do not see an option in the export wizard to change types. And if I try to create the table ahead of time and do the export I get the following error:

```
Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE "ABC" (
"XYZ" i..." failed with the following error: "ERROR [42P07] ERROR: relation "ABC" already exists;
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:
Do all the steps as described in the link in my question,when you get to the point in the wizard where you select your table, after selecting your table name will appear in the next column "Destination" double click it and select the correct type for your destination.

happy coding!

Comment: I already have the correct type selected but it still gives me this error.