# Error [IM014] exporting SQL Server database to PostgreSQL using export with ODBC pg driver

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc

I am trying to export a DB from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. The simplest way seems using the export tool in SSMS as I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370326/migrate-data-from-ms-sql-to-postgresql/50919468#50919468) .

But I get the following error:

> ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch

which means components mismatch between x64 and x86.

My SQL Server 2019 is 64 bit, PostgreSQL is version 15 64 bit, and the ODBC driver that comes with StackBuilder on installation is 64 bit too as seen here:

[image: []]

The destination configuration in SSMS is the following:

[image: []]

I have installed additional x64 ODBC driver from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) but with the same result.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong and why I have architecture mismatch, thank you.

Comment: Are you using the 32bit or 64bit import wizard?

Comment: Right click->task->export data,  I don't know the wizard version.

Comment: Sounds like you are using the 32bit wizard from SSMS/SSDT; that won't support the 64bit driver. If you want/need to use the 64bit driver, you need to (install and) launch the 64bit import/export wizard which only comes packaged with the SQL Server installer.

Comment: I have downloaded the 32 bit version of ODBC driver so now it has platform 64/32 bit and now it works. Thanks!